# Search for categories

Tags: plugins, categories, ajax, search

I would like to propose on my site a search engine allowing to find categories (with suggestions), and not posts or pages.

I tried different plugins, including [ajax search lite](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/), but without success, because it always necesseray to select as source article or page.

Do you know a solution? 
With Ajax search lite or others?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use default wordpress function to search categories. 
get_terms() is the function you need to use where you need to pass your search string in a search parameter.

For details please check get_terms function in wordpress codex